# Installing a patio door on top of a concrete border

Tags: concrete, doors, garage, sealing, cutting

I'm installing a 6' patio door in my garage that leads out to our back yard. Around the floor of the garage is a 6" poured concrete ledge/border that the walls are built on.

My current plan is to take out a section of the wall and build the door *directly on top* of that 6" concrete ledge, perhaps building a single step inside and outside the garage to make walking through the door a little easier. My thought is that setting the door on top of the ledge will be significantly easier than trying to cut out the concrete, and then I wouldn't have to worry about water running under the door.

Two related questions:

1. Does this seem like a reasonable idea? I don't expect this to be a high-traffic doorway so I don't think I'll mind the step, but I'm not sure if this would raise any issues with code (or if the extra 6" will be annoying).
2. What should I put between the concrete and the bottom of the door? My current plan is simply to seal it with silicon but I'm not sure if that will be adequate. I've read that some recommend adding a wood sill below the door but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Thanks!

Adding a couple photos for reference:

[image: garage interior]

[image: garage exterior]

Comment: The 6" *will* be annoying, but that's better than breaking the bathtub. Prob violates landing requirements, but with a single 6" step I'm not sure. Use *sill tape* such as, TITE-SEAL Self-adhesive waterproof flashing tape 4-in x 33-ft Rubberized Asphalt Roll Flashing, and make sure you bring it up the sides a few inches. Also, nice hammer.